# Angular 7 launch an alert component from the guard when user leave a page in order to inform

Tags: angular

I' m using Angular 7 and I have several links (home page, login and so on).
I have a page with a form.

I wish to launch an alert (a component alert with my graphic) if the user leave the page (the form) in order to ask if wishes to remain here (on the form) or to go the new page or to save the form and after to go new page.

My routes are managed by guards:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent,
    canDeactivate: [LoginGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'help',
    component: HelpComponent,
    canDeactivate: [LoginGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'team',
    component: TeamComponent,
    canDeactivate: [LoginGuard]
  },
[...]
```

Where the LoginGaurd is my service:

```
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class LoginGuard implements CanActivate, CanDeactivate<boolean>
{
  private subscription: Subscription;
  private user: User;

  public isChange:boolean = true;

  constructor
  (
    private loginService: LoginService,
    private router: Router,
    private userService: UserService,
  )
  {

  }

  ngOnInit(): void
  {
    this.subscription = this.userService.user$.subscribe(user => this.user = user);
    this.updateUser();
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void
  {

  }

  canDeactivate()
  {
    if(!this.isChange)
      return confirm(""); //I wish to change this alert with my alert (a Component alert)
    else
    {
      return true;
    }
  }

  canActivate()
  {
    if (this.loginService.getIsLogged())
    {
      this.subscription = this.userService.user$.subscribe(user => this.user = user);

      this.updateUser();
      this.subscription.unsubscribe();
      return true;
    } else
    {
      this.loginService.setLogoutVariables();
      this.router.navigateByUrl('');
      return false;
    }
  }
[...]
```

I wish to change this:

```
 return confirm(""); //I wish to change this alert with my alert (a Component alert)
```

beacuse it is not nice (I cannot use Angular Material or others libs).